# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() (PDO, php)

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get data from a table using a public function in PHP, but I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() (PDO, php)

I'm searching for 2, 3 hours... But no result is similar or I did not understand.

```
<?php

class Config {

    public static $SQL;

    private function __construct() {
        $host_name = "localhost";
        $base_user = "root";
        $base_pass = "";
        $base_name = "home_page";

        try {
            self::$SQL = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name;dbname=$base_name", $base_user, $base_pass);
            self::$SQL->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Connected successfully";
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die("Something went wrong, database connection closed. Reason: ". $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function GetData($table, $data, $id) {
        $wc = Config::$SQL->prepare('SELECT `'.$data.'` FROM `'.$table.'` WHERE `ID` = ?');
        $wc->execute(array($id));
        $r_data = $wc->fetch();
        return $r_data[$data];
    }

}

?>
```

And I use this in my base file:

```
<h1><?php echo Config::GetData("page_details", "Moto", 1) ?></h1>
```

The error is from this line:

```
$wc = self::$SQL->prepare('SELECT `'.$data.'` FROM `'.$table.'` WHERE `ID` = ?');
```

Comment: Where and when do you create an `Config` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any particular reason why you want to use `STATIC`everywhere? The common approach is using public, dynamic methods and properties. I rewrote your sample with *suggested* naming convention in PHPs OOP, it works:

```php
<?php

class Config
{

    /** @var PDO $conn */
    private $conn = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $host_name = "localhost";
        $base_user = "root";
        $base_pass = "";
        $base_name = "home_page";

        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name;dbname=$base_name", $base_user, $base_pass);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Connected successfully"; // <- this is unnnesesary
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("Something went wrong, database connection closed. Reason: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function findById($table, $data, $id)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT `' . $data . '` FROM `' . $table . '` WHERE `uid` = ?');
        $stmt->execute(array($id));

        return  $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

}

// just for test
$cfg = new Config();
print_r($cfg->findById('foo', '*', 1));
```

or in your case

```php
<?php echo $cfg->findById("page_details", "Moto", 1)['Moto'] ?>
```

Comment: Actually should also mention that by design your class should be called `Connection` and **find*** methods should be placed in repository class(es) but it's up to you.

Comment: Now I get this error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

On line: $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT `' . $data . '` FROM `' . $table . '` WHERE `uid` = ?');

Comment: You still call your class/method statically, show us how? If you tested _as it is_ my example you'd see it works.

Comment: Yes, your exemple work. I use the function like this -> ```<?php echo Connection::findById("page_details", "Moto", 1) ?>```. But, you exemple return this -> ```Array ( [Moto] => My moto! )``` and i need just "My moto!".

Comment: It is a suggestion that you should go this way. Why do you still want to use static methods and properties? BTW by definition constructor should not be private.

Comment: Make it non-static, create an instance of `Connection` class at the beginning of the script and then access methods of the instance. That's really how it's supposed to be done.

Comment: Check my edit, last lines, can't you see a difference between echoing the whole array instead of its indexed values?